# Swap "Part" and corresponding number

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, parts

I am trying to figure out how I can swap the word "Part" and the part's number in my document. The default style for `\part{mypartname}` is something like:

Part I:

mypartname

However, I want it to be

I Part:

mypartname

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? I use `scrbook` as document class.

Best wishes and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `scrbook` allows this by redefining `\partformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{%
  \thepart\autodot~\partname:%
}

\begin{document}
\part{My part name}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the standard `report` document class to achieve this as follows.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart}
                 {\huge\bfseries \thepart\nobreakspace\partname}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{The first}
\part{The second}
\end{document}
```